# SemanticUI modals is always closable, regardless of configuration

Tags: semantic-ui

I am using Semantic UI and I am pretty happy using it. I am facing a small issue. I am trying to implement a `Modal`, a full screen one. I do not want that modal to be closable (ie. click on dimmer closes modal). So as per the documentation I implemented following to show a non closable modal.

```
$("body").find(".processing-loader")
.modal("setting", "closable", false).modal("show");
```

But the modal closes when clicked anywhere on dimmer.

Comment: This was probably a fixed bug. Now it works correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/r1ne6k4j/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure which part of the documentation led you to the `.modal("setting", "closable", false)` syntax, but this is what SemanticUI expects from you:

```
element.modal(settings).modal(behavior, arguments...);
```

so here we go:

```
$("body").find(".processing-loader").modal({closable: true}).modal('show')
```

Use a single plain object with your configuration as a parameter and it will work just fine :) Also make sure you use the newest version of the library.

Comment: Well I was able to figure out the issue in my code. Thank you and yes ofcourse your answer helped as well.

Comment: well, indeed the new version works with both 'setting' and configuration object syntax, just tried it, you just need to be careful to pass true not 'true'. Good that it works now :)